# How to set Trac's auth?

Tags: debian, authentication, deployment, trac

I'm deploying a standalone Trac instance and getting stuck at this message when trying to log in:

> Authentication information not available. Please refer to the installation documentation.

I have referred to the documentation already. I'm running the instance with this command:

```
tracd -p 8000 --auth='todos,trac-test/swords2.txt,trac' trac-test
```

I also generated *trac-test/swords2.txt* with a script from [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/demo-1.0/wiki/TracStandalone#GeneratingPasswordsWithoutApache), which looks like this:

```
xliiv:trac:abeeba17773e4c9a2cbe75d9a1c84ea6
```

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is rather useless for others, because i failed :D

According to documentation:

```
$ tracd -p port --auth="BASE_PROJECT_DIR,password_file_path,realm" project_path
```

I typed *project name* like this:

```
tracd -p 8000 --auth="todos,trac-test/swords.txt,trac" trac-test
```

instead of *procect dir name* like this:

```
tracd -p 8000 --auth="trac-test,trac-test/swords.txt,trac" trac-test
```